# Could Powershell Out-File be silently failing to write lines to a file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have a powershell script that loops through a list of products, and calls a web service to get data for each product, then writes that out to a .csv file. Recently we discovered that there are intermittently a few lines missing from the output file.

I've done everything I can to verify the web service is working correctly, and any failure is getting caught by the exception handler.

That leaves the Out-File commandlet as the only potential problem, but if that were throwing any exceptions it should be caught as well.

Is there a possibility out-File is failing without throwing an exception? And if so is there a way to determine that it failed and retry the operation?

```
try
    {
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12                
        $data = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://somewebservice.com"
        
        $csvOutput = ParseToCsv $data

        Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputFile -InputObject $csvOutput
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "ERROR Exception"
        Write-Host $csvOutput -Separator "`n"             
    }
```

Comment: Maybe add a ```write-host $csvOutput``` just before the ```Out-File``` and reconcile the console output with the contents of ```$outputFile``` - are the lines missing from the console output as well, or just the output file? Also, are you sure ```ParseToCsv``` is actually returning a value for the "missing" log entries?

Comment: You ned an array and when only one output line from the file you will get nothing.  Try : $csvOutput = @(ParseToCsv $data)

Comment: To actually handle errors using `catch`, you need to set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` before the first command whose error you want to catch. Alternatively pass `-ErrorAction Stop` to each command.